# Two port network z parameter determination

Tags: electrical, network

[image: image shows solution in book]

[image: this is how I solved it]

I would like to know how it is solved in book as I found that it is way quicker than the way I solved. Any detailed explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See The first write the definition equations for Z parameter and then make I2 =0 and You'll be able to find Z11 similarly proceed with for other parameters just keep defining equations of Z parameters in mind .